# What is the proper way of calling a superclass constructor in Scala?

Tags: inheritance, scala

Suppose I would like to extend class `C`, getting `SubC`.

Now I would like to access the variable `c` in `SubC` as presented in the example below in the method `printC`.

The following does not work, as calling `printC` on a `SubC` instance will print `SubC`'s `c` and not `C`'s `c` (I guess I could have picked better names...)

```
class C(protected var c : Int) {
  def update(n : Int) {
    c = n
  }
}

class SubC(c: Int) extends C(c) {
  def printC : Unit = {
    println(c)
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val subC = new SubC(1)
    subC.update(3)
    subC.printC // prints 1
  }
}
```

A possible (but undesirable) solution would be:

```
class SubC(cc: Int) extends C(cc) {
  def printC = {
    println(c)
  }
}
```

This works but it introduces a new (and unneeded) identifier `cc` into scope.

Is there a better (cleaner) way of doing this?

PS: To put the example above into some context. What I actually want to do is to augment `C` with some traits without introducing new identifiers into scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is probably the best way to augment C with traits without introducing new identifiers in scope:

```
class C(protected var c : Int) {
  def update(n : Int) {
    c = n
  }
}

trait CanPrintC {
  self: C =>
  def printC : Unit = {
      println(c)
  }
}
class SubC(c: Int) extends C(c) with CanPrintC 

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val subC = new SubC(1)
    subC.update(3)
    subC.printC // prints 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice thinking... the problem with this solution is that it creates a dependency between CanPrintC and C... I might have several traits from a different package and creating a wrapper for each of them seems like a lot of code would be duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Use self types:

```
class SubC(c: Int) extends C(c) {  
  self: C =>
  def printC : Unit = {            
    println(self.c)              
  }
}
```